Read DeltaTable of crate deltalake-core - skipping _last_checkpoint
For my own datastore I have implemented the object_store trait. Now I want to use the crate deltalake-core to read a deltalake table on my datastore.
let mut dtbuilder = match DeltaTableBuilder::from_valid_uri(table_host_path) {
    Err(err) => {
        error!("Failed creating DeltaTableBuilder: {}",err.to_string());
        return Err("An error occurred".into());
    },
    Ok(dt) => dt,
    };

dtbuilder = dtbuilder.with_version(0);
let dt = dtbuilder.load().await?;

This works but once the deltalake table does not have a "_last_checkpoint" file in _delta_log it fails. I have tried to implement my own LogStore but have now clue how to skip reading the _last_checkpoint. Also passing explicitly the version=0 does not help.
Does anyone an idea how to cope with this issue?

Error in the implementation of object_store:
deltalake-core is explicitly testing on the object_store::Error:NotFound when trying to download "_last_checkpoint", but my object_store-implementation returned object_store::Error::Generic.
